# How big (in number of questions or active users) are the Portuguese and English versions of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, languages, portuguese-stack-overflow

I'm trying to understand the difference in size between the English and Portuguese versions of Stack Overflow, so I can explain to Brazilian developers how crucial it is to learn English, and how much they're losing by just sticking to a single language, and one that's not the main language in technology.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=228507&tab=reputation&filter=month vs https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?page=2103&tab=reputation&filter=month

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions vs https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: @Mahezer, does that answer your question? You can also use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/queries) to make queries against both main SO and PT.so.

Comment: While I'm not opposing to the idea do know that the sole reason SO.pt exists for those that can't or won't learn a second language.

Comment: I grew up in a country where 6 years of English was mandatory to graduate high school.  But it is a very small country, and Brazil is certainly not small.  208 million people ought to be enough to find somebody to help you in your native language :)  64% of the USA population, not knowing another language is quite normal there.

Comment: @HansPassant, problem is: According to [this link](https://www.internetworldstats.com/stats7.htm), about 1/4 of the internet is written in english. Not to mention, every command in the most popular programming languages are written in english (For example: it's common to see `print` or `while` keywords in languages)

Comment: That link tells you that you are better off learning Chinese :)  Tough language, I never got much beyond knowing how to order beer.

Comment: @HansPassant True enough, hahah. However, this is a report looking at the whole internet. My interest is in the technology section. 

And if I measure difficulty to learn versus ammount of content, I can easily know that I take way less time to learn english, and don't lose that much in terms of content (specially in the technology section, I would bet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many statistics for [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) that may interest you:

[image: SE stats example]

I have quite often drawn attention to the existence of [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to SO users without a PortugueseSO account who seemed to find good English a bit of a struggle and several times the reaction was along the lines "Yes, I know but there is more expertise on SO" or "But I expect a better answer, quicker, here". (Given time, this may change.)

For spoken languages Portuguese is the [6th most popular](https://www.babbel.com/en/magazine/the-10-most-spoken-languages-in-the-world/) and English only three places higher (native speakers percentage of the world population (2007) [3.08%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers), relative to 5.52%) but the difference is in L2 speakers ([13.8 million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers) for Portuguese as opposed to 743.5 million for English).

English (or American!) is not only the *"lingua franca"* for Information Technology but also the language of many films and videos, standard in the oil and gas sector around the world and mandatory for air transport.

[@yivi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364955/how-big-in-number-of-questions-or-active-users-are-the-portuguese-and-english#comment567405_364956) has mentioned [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=60#graph) and a comparison of charts (like that below for PortugueseSO) may be of interest:

[image: SEDE chart for PortugueseSO]

The raw numbers may be downloaded for analysis.

Answer (score 3):

The numbers are largely irrelevant. It should be about the quality of the content. Just because the main site has a massively larger amount of questions and active users does not indicate that the quality of the content is better.

Learning another language is a choice, but it will improve anybody that chooses to go down that path... regardless of the content that becomes available to you as a developer.

Comment: Is there a (perceived/significant) difference in quality between SO.en and the localized sites?

Comment: @rene Personally, I haven't been impressed with the Spanish version. But maybe I should give it another go...

Comment: @rene I have no idea, as I don't speak any languages fluently enough to visit a localized site. Was just indicating quantity != quality

Comment: @Tanner really, quantity != quality. However, more engagement is inevitably linked with higher problem discovering/solving. Also, bigger community means more ways to solve the same problem, each solutions fitting the best for a certain situation

Comment: @MahezerCarvalho I'm not trying to argue this either way. I just wouldn't ask people to learn a language so that they can access the main SO site rather than a localized version. Learning a new language like English would have much greater benefits for a person that aren't related to SO.

Comment: @Tanner agreed :)

Comment: @Tanner I use SO just as an example of the ammount of knowledge they're leaving behind if they choose to stay with one single language :)